# Website starting up on PC boot

Tags: virus

today i boot my PC when i got home & a russian website about games & naked chicks openen up instantly during general boot of the desktop. I thought "WTF", shut down my PC and restarted it.

Now i must say my dad uses this PC aswell (since my parents are all like "we don't care if you paid for it, if it's in our house it's ours) and to say the least he'd click on every tit pic he sees on the internet... + he uses it for banking stuff and all that too o_O *sigh*

How can i check if there's a virus? And where it is? I've checked tasklist & the current running processes, compared PIDs but nothing jumps out as if i've been keylogged or sthing, so i guess it's just a small virus/pop up thingy. And last of all how can i get rid of it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "and to say the least he'd click on every tit pic he sees on the internet... + he uses it for banking stuff and all that too" Sounds like he needs a small talk about security...

Comment: This is not the kind of forum you are looking for and it's likely this question would be flagged or removed. I suggest heading over to [Combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/) for tools, and help with this

Comment: Trust me, i had to upload a "virus" on the PC upstairs which he used before, that when internet explorer ran it would shutdown the PC :) and put it in startup file. THATS how he learned (sort of)...

Comment: Add a password on boot. Or if that's politically infeasible, add two separate operating systems where yours is encrypted with TrueCrypt. That way you only need to kill your dad's OS when he screws it up.

Comment: Bah, it's truly abominable how parents are so stupid on the internet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser hijacked - how to fix and prevent?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/browser-hijacked-how-to-fix-and-prevent)

Comment: @CodesInChaos BIOS and any hardware threat is still there tho...

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I recommend nuking it from orbit and restoring from a well known backup. If you really need to find out, have a look at [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk) it's an offline bootable disk that will scan your computer for pesky viruses.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i'll check it out, so restoring it to a previous date should/could fix it?

Comment: Yep, normally it should

Comment: There are free anti-virus tools that you should also consider using, if paid options are not an option for you. No AV is perfect, but it looks like you need all the help you can get.